# Set a Index type unique in this table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have problem on set a Index type unique in this table MySQL.

In the table `doTable` I have set a Index type unique on `MyUniqueKey` with fields `EventDate` and `TES`.

I expect that when `EventDate` and `TES` are already the insert query does not is executed.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `doTable`;
CREATE TABLE `doTable` (
  `EventDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `TES` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dicl` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVHS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MyUniqueKey` (`EventDate`,`TES`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need insert into `doTable` the old rows of `doTable_old` and tried this code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `doTable` (
    `EventDate`,
    `TES`,
    `Dicl`,
    `AVHS`
) SELECT
    `EventDate`,
    `TES`,
    SUM(`Dicl`),
    SUM(`AVHS`)
FROM                
`doTable_old`
WHERE
`EventDate` = '2015-02-05'
`TES` = 'M201';
```

In effect when `EventDate` and `TES` are already the insert query does not is executed in `doTable`.

Now I need update the value of field `Dicl` on `doTable` with a new algorithm and I have tried this:

```
UPDATE IGNORE `doTable` A
JOIN (
    SELECT
        SUM(tmp0.`Dicl`) AS `Dicl`
    FROM
        `doTable_cons` tmp
    JOIN `doTable_old` tmp0 ON tmp0.Codes = tmp.Codes
    WHERE
        `TES` = 'M201'
    AND `EventDate` = '2015-02-05'
    GROUP BY
        `EventDate`
    ORDER BY
        `EventDate` ASC
) AS x
SET A.`Dicl` = A.`Dicl` + x.`Dicl`
WHERE
    A.`TES` = x.`TES`;
```

Instead in this case the the value of field `Dicl` on `doTable` is always updated even if `EventDate` and `TES` are already on `doTable`.

I mean, if I take the old line 10 when I update +2 the first time the new value is 12 and if I try again to update the value 14 and then 16 and then 18 ... should stay at 12 ... but the key is not working ...

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand ...

Comment: `TES` is a varchar(4) field, you're searching for `4` characters already, so what's the point of `LIKE '%M201%'`? You might as well just use `TES = 'M201'`

Comment: Okay I have correct but I don't have solved my problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate keys only come into play when you change the fields used in the unique key in a way that'd cause a duplicate violation to occur, or you're inserting NEW records that'd cause a violation.

With your second query, you're not changing EITHER field used in your unique key. Therefore the update will proceed, because no violation is occuring.

e.g.

table X  (uniquey key (x,y))

```
x    y   z
1    1   0
1    2   0


INSERT (x,y) VALUES (1,1) // fails - would create a dupe violation
INSERT (x,Y) VALUES (1,3) // succeeds - no dupe
UPDATE ... SET y=2 WHERE x=1 AND y=1 // fails - would create a dupe
UPDATE ... SET z=z+1 where x=1 AND y=1 // no problem, no dupe
```

In other words, by your logic, it'd be impossible to update ANY records in a database, because any changes on the table would create a dupe key violation. That's obviously utterly wrong.

Comment: Okay thank you for explanation ... but I have on method for resolving this problem?

Comment: If you don't want your records updated, then exclude them at the `where` clause level.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand